# FileZilla won't connect to server using key authentication?

Tags: macos, sftp, filezilla, ubuntu-16.04, ssh-keys

I've been following the Linode guide for [hosting a website](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website), and it suggests using FileZilla to upload your files to the newly configured server.

My server is protected by key authentication, with a 4096 RSA key. No matter what I've tried, I can't get FileZilla to connect to my server. I keep getting an error for `"No supported authentication methods available"`.

I tried adding the key manually to the SFTP settings in FileZilla, to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

I'm on MacOS 10.12.6, my server is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and it's FileZilla 3.27.1

Thanks again,

– Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it to work, even though I didn't do anything different, at least not knowingly. Go figure. If anyone else is having issues with this, here's what I suggest:

1. Make sure you've followed all the steps in Linode's "Securing your server" guide. This means generating a key and passphrase, adding a LUA, etc.
2. Make sure your LUA has write access to your `/var/www/` directory.
3. Add your private key to FileZilla's settings, under SFTP. You can show hidden files in Finder with CMD+SHIFT+PERIOD
4. In the main window of FileZilla, enter your server IPv4 address, your LUA Username & Password, and Port 22.
5. Everything should connect, and you should be able to add files to your new web server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the steps listed under the "Prerequisites" here?

https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/file-transfer/filezilla

Securing your server... and then trying to log into the server via SSH? SFTP uses the same authentication method than SSH. Trying to log in via SSH will teach you more about what goes wrong when it goes wrong. If SSH'ing into the server works, then SFTP won't be much of a problem.

May I also suggest Forklift as FTP client? There's a version (athough not the latest one) free on the Mac App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/be/app/forklift-file-manager-and-ftp-sftp-webdav-amazon-s3-client/id412448059?mt=12

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what I did, but I got it working. I think my brain just needed a reset.